# Create DateRangePicker using two MUI X DatePicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x

I'm trying to build a DateRangePicker using MUI RangePickers, but I don't know how to use one only calendar to select the start date and the end date.

This is what I tried:

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-wescoff-759vfm?file=/src/App.tsx

I'm not using the DateRangePicker from mui-x-pro, since it's only available in pro plan.

How can I make the two inputs to use one single calendar to select a range ?

Comment: Why can't you use other daterange picker libraries like react-dates, if the daterangepicker from MUI is not free?

Comment: @remondo unfortunately I can't, I need to use the datePicker from MUI since it's heavily customized on our side

Comment: Also, react-dates only supports React up to version 16 and has no plans to get support for React v17 or v18

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you want one calendar where you can press a start  date and an end date and then these are highlighted. I have solved this but I haven't done much about the design so that will be up to you. I have solved the problem using the `DatePicker` elements `renderDay` property.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import TextField, { TextFieldProps } from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { DatePicker, DatePickerProps } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker';
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import { PickersDay } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/PickersDay';

const DateRangePickerStyled = styled('div')(() => ({
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
}));

const DateRangePicker = (props: DateRangePickerProps) => {
    const { value, onChange, ...rest } = props;
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = React.useState(0);
    const [endDate, setEndDate] = React.useState(0);
    const [datesPicked, setDatesPicked] = React.useState(0);

    return (
        <DateRangePickerStyled>
            <DatePicker
                value={new Date()}
                minDate={startDate}
                onChange={(date: any) => {
                    setDatesPicked(datesPicked + 1);
                    if (datesPicked % 2 !== 0) {
                        setEndDate(date.$D);
                    } else {
                        setStartDate(date.$D);
                        setEndDate(0);
                    }
                }}
                closeOnSelect={false}
                renderDay={(day, _value, DayComponentProps) => {
                    const isSelected =
                        !DayComponentProps.outsideCurrentMonth &&
                        Array.from(
                            { length: endDate - startDate + 2 },
                            (x, i) => i + startDate - 1
                        ).indexOf(day.date()) > 0;
                    return (
                        <div
                            style={
                                isSelected
                                    ? {
                                            backgroundColor: 'blue',
                                      }
                                    : {}
                            }
                            key={day.toString()}
                        >
                            <PickersDay {...DayComponentProps} />
                        </div>
                    );
                }}
                {...rest}
            />
        </DateRangePickerStyled>
    );
};

export default function MaterialUIPickers() {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState<DateRangePickerValueType | null>(
        null
    );

    return (
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
            <DateRangePicker
                value={value}
                onChange={(newValue) => {
                    setValue(newValue as DateRangePickerValueType);
                }}
                renderInput={(params: TextFieldProps) => (
                    <TextField {...params} />
                )}
            />
        </LocalizationProvider>
    );
}

type DateRangePickerValueType = {
    start: unknown;
    end: unknown;
};

interface DateRangePickerProps
    extends Omit<DatePickerProps<unknown, unknown>, 'value'> {
    value: DateRangePickerValueType | null;
}
```

More examples of this method can be found on:
https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/
If you also want to limit which dates are selectable I would suggest using the `minDate` property.
If I've misunderstood what it is you wanted or my solution is not all the way there feel free to leave a comment and I'll take an extra look, hope it helps :-)